# Efficiently computing Khatri-Rao like sum (pairwise row sum)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

I'm trying to compute [Khatri-Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Khatri%E2%80%93Rao_product) like sum (i.e. pairwise row sum) and was able to come up with this solution:

```
In [15]: arr1
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [16]: arr2
Out[16]: 
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [13, 14, 15]])

# for every row in `arr1`, sum it with all rows in `arr2` (in pairwise manner)
In [17]: np.repeat(arr1, arr2.shape[0], 0) + np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))
Out[17]: 
array([[12, 14, 16],
       [13, 15, 17],
       [14, 16, 18],
       [13, 15, 17],
       [14, 16, 18],
       [15, 17, 19],
       [14, 16, 18],
       [15, 17, 19],
       [16, 18, 20]])

# thus `axis0` in the result will become `arr1.shape[0] * arr2.shape[0]`
In [18]: (np.repeat(arr1, arr2.shape[0], 0) + np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))).shape
Out[18]: (9, 3)
```

It works perfectly fine. However, I was wondering whether is this the **optimized way** to do this computation. I also timed the computation time for a (fairly) large array

```
# inputs
In [69]: arr1 = np.arange(9000).reshape(100, 90)
In [70]: arr2 = np.arange(45000).reshape(500, 90)

In [71]: (np.repeat(arr1, arr2.shape[0], 0) + np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))).shape
Out[71]: (50000, 90)

In [72]: %timeit np.repeat(arr1, arr2.shape[0], 0) + np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))
22.5 ms ± 420 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is it possible to optimize it further, maybe using more sophisticated approaches?

Also, I'm not completely sure about whether [`numpy.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can be leveraged here.. Because, as far as I understand, it can't be used to increase the shape of the resultant array, which is what is happening here. I welcome corrections, suggestions, and improvements to my solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage `broadcasting` -

```
(arr1[:,None] + arr2).reshape(-1,arr1.shape[1])
```

For large arrays, we can gain some further speedup with [`numexpr`](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) to transfer the `broadcasting` part -

```
import numexpr as ne

arr1_3D = arr1[:,None]
out = ne.evaluate('arr1_3D + arr2').reshape(-1,arr1.shape[1])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [545]: arr1 = np.random.rand(500,500)

In [546]: arr2 = np.random.rand(500,500)

In [547]: %timeit (arr1[:,None] + arr2).reshape(-1,arr1.shape[1])
1 loop, best of 3: 215 ms per loop

In [548]: %%timeit
     ...: arr1_3D = arr1[:,None]
     ...: out = ne.evaluate('arr1_3D + arr2').reshape(-1,arr1.shape[1])
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop
```

Comment: So, does `np.tile` and `np.repeat` make a copy of the array? Is that the reason my solution is slow when compared to yours? Of course, using `numexper` seems to do the trick even better as we've seen in an earlier example

Comment: @kmario23 Yup, we are being memory efficient here and hence the benefits. In fact, with tile and repeat we are occupying more memory than the inputs.